# Bin a continuous variable without getting C901 flake8 too complex

Tags: python, flake8

I know `pandas` and `numpy` have binning functionalities, such as `pd.cut` and `np.digitalize`. But these come in useful when having large arrays / lists / dataframes. For my purposes it seems overkill to use these methods, since it's just a single variable in my project.

Right now I have a single continuous variable and I use the following function to bin it (make it discrete):

```py
def bin_data(self):  # noqa: C901
    if self.value <= 300000:
        bin_cat = 999
    elif 300000 < self.value <= 500000:
        bin_cat = 15000
    elif 500000 < self.value <= 1000000:
        bin_cat = 30000
    elif 1000000 < self.value <= 2200000:
        bin_cat = 60000
    elif 2200000 < self.value <= 4400000:
        bin_cat = 120000
    elif 4400000 < self.value <= 8800000:
        bin_cat = 180000
    elif 8800000 < self.value <= 17500000:
        bin_cat = 300000
    elif 17500000 < self.value <= 35000000:
        bin_cat = 600000
    elif 35000000 < self.value <= 70000000:
        bin_cat = 900000
    elif 70000000 < self.value <= 140000000:
        bin_cat = 1500000
    else:
        bin_cat = 3000000
```

But this results in a flake8 error `C901: function too complex`.

Two questions:

1. What is wrong with the code like this, I don't find it "complex".
2. How would we make this "easier"?

Comment: *Complex* here is an arbitrary limit set by `flake8`. It's not an error, it's a complaint about code style. Look up the message in the `flake8` docs to find out how many `elif`s it thinks are okay. Then ignore or disable the message and carry on.

Comment: I see, so for now the solution is to ignore it like we did with `noqa`.

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind that all `flake8` can see is an 11-way `if`-test. That can be a sign of logic in code that should really reside in data: for example, a lookup in a `dict`. But that isn't the case here, because it is a range-based lookup, and `flake8` can't know that there isn't really a simpler way to write that in Python.

Comment: I see, thanks for the information! @BoarGules

Comment: not saying this code is complex, but you may be able to write this in a less error-prone less-complex way with a loop over some `(start, end, result)` tuples.  note also that flake8 does not detect complexity by default, you have to opt into that behaviour by setting a threshold -- the current flake8 maintainer.

Comment: I see, and I also understand that "complex" is a multi interpretable subject and you have to draw the line somewhere. But I am actually curious what you mean with the proposed method with the tuples @AnthonySottile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not saying this code is complex, but you may be able to write this in a less error-prone less-complex way with a loop over some `(end, result)` tuples. note also that flake8 does not detect complexity by default, you have to opt into that behaviour by setting a threshold

Since it didnt't fit in the comments section, here's an alternative way to write this while satisfying the complexity

```py
BINS = (
    (300000, 999),
    (500000, 15000),
    (1000000, 30000),
    (2200000, 60000),
    (4400000, 120000),
    (8800000, 180000),
    (17500000, 300000),
    (35000000, 600000),
    (70000000, 900000),
    (14000000, 1600000), 
)
OTHERWISE = 3000000


def bin_data(value):
    for max_n, bucket in BINS:
        if value <= max_n:
            return bucket
    else:
        return OTHERWISE
```

---

disclaimer: though I don't think it matters for this particular information, I'm the current flake8 maintainer